# Why aren't all the names in dir(x) valid for attribute access?

Tags: python, introspection, python-datamodel

Why would a coder stuff things into `__dict__` that can't be used for attribute access? For example, in my Plone instance, `dir(portal)` includes `index_html`, but `portal.index_html` raises AttributeError. This is also true for the `__class__` attribute of `Products.ZCatalog.Catalog.mybrains`. Is there a good reason why `dir()` can't be trusted?

Poking around the `inspect` module, I see they use `object.__dict__['x']` instead of attribute access for this reason and because they do not want to trigger `getattr` magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Plone, so the following is general.

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) of `dir`:

> If the object has a method named
>   `__dir__()`, this method will be called and must return the list of
>   attributes. This allows objects that
>   implement a custom `__getattr__()` or
>   `__getattribute__()` function to customize the way `dir()` reports their
>   attributes.

Just guessing here, but I can think of two things that may be happening--

- The object has a `__dir__()` method that returns attributes that it doesn't have
- (less likely) The object *has* the attribute you're asking for (i.e. it's in `obj.__dict__` or `type(obj).__dict__`, but overrides `__getattr__` to return `AttributeError`

**EDIT**: `__dir__` is only supported in Python 2.6+, however the (deprecated) special attributes `__methods__` and `__members__` can be used instead for earlier versions.

Comment: `__dir__` is new in python 2.6, and IIRC Zope still doesn't run on anything newer than python 2.4.

Comment: That's true, I am using Python 2.4. Zope does not yet officially run on newer Python although it has been done experimentally.